# Update Active Directory from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ldap, odbc

I have linked SQL Server into Active Directory and am trying to use PHP to create an ODBC connection to pull in the data. I can read from Active Directory fine but when I try and update it using SQL UPDATE, I get this error

```
 Msg 7390, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
 The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" does not support the required transaction interface.
```

I know I have to use PHP's LDAP functions but I am not sure how to rewrite the LDAP string to use in PHP. My best guess would be:

I tried (example string): 
    OU=staff,DC=example,DC=internal

but this doesn't work. My question is: assuming there is no way of updating Active Directory from my SQL view, how do I go about updating LDAP with PHP?

Comment: What are you trying to update exactly in LDAP? What specific properties on the users? Do you have any code with the PHP LDAP functions you have tried yet?

Comment: givenName, sn, mail, title, company, department, telephonenumber and cn

Comment: And my LDAP code fails to bind:

Comment: function updateActiveDirectory($user)
 {
          $server     = "DC-1";
          $unit           = "OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal";
          $ds                = ldap_connect($server);
          if(!$ds)
          {
               return FALSE;
          }
          $bind = ldap_bind($ds, "Administrator", "password");
          if(!$bind)
          {
               return FALSE;
          }
          ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
          $sr = ldap_search($ds, $unit, "(samaccountname={$user}");
     }

Comment: Then it tells me I  have bad search filters